# TFS 2010 and creating a package

Tags: deployment, tfs, tfsbuild

I am running the build with the flags  `/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=True`

The agent creates a the folder:

```
C:\Builds\99\MyWebProject\Sources\WebProj\Web\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp
```

that is used when the package is deployed. However, this folder does NOT have the files that are not in source control but are created during the post build event. I'd like these files to be included in the package as well (but can't add them to the source control as they are created later).

How do I take care of this issue?

Comment: Are those files setup to be copied to the output location during the build process? By the way, there's a Stack Exchange proposal for a Visual Studio ALM Q&A site that you can help to go live: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could do this was to add files to source control.